# Php mysql select statement with variables (Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens)

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

Need to `SELECT` mysql data based on user input.

For example, in input form (fields) user enters day, month, year. And need to get (fetch) mysql data that matches the entered day, month and year.

Here is my code:

```
if (strlen($_POST['date_day'] > 0)) {
$post_date_day = $_POST['date_day'];
$date_day = 'RecordDay = ?';
}
if (strlen($_POST['date_month'] > 0)) {
$post_date_month = $_POST['date_month'];
$date_month = ' and RecordMonth = ?';
}
if (strlen($_POST['date_year'] > 0)) {
$post_date_year = $_POST['date_year'];
$date_year = ' and RecordYear = ?';
}

if ( strlen( $_POST['date_day'] or $_POST['date_month'] or $_POST['date_year'] ) > 0 ) {
$where = 'WHERE';
}

$sql_prepare = $where .$date_day .$date_month .$date_year;
$sql_execute = array($post_date_day, $post_date_month, $post_date_year);


$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal $sql_prepare ");
$sql->execute($sql_execute);
```

If strlen of $_POST['date_day'] and $_POST['date_month'] and $_POST['date_year'] is more than 0, then the script works.

But if, for example, user leaves year blank (because want to see all results that match day and month), I get error `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`.

Do not understand why does not match number of tokens. Because

```
if (strlen($_POST['date_year'] > 0)) {
$post_date_year = $_POST['date_year'];
$date_year = ' and RecordYear = ?';
}
```

I suppose if (strlen($_POST['date_year'] == 0) then $post_date_year and $date_year is blank; so there is no variable, nor token.

Possibly my method to get solution is wrong and there is some good working method.....

Comment: `strlen($_POST['date_year']) > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using round brackets in a wrong way

```
(strlen($_POST['date_year'] > 0))
```

You should count post variable so surround `$_POST['date_year']` with round brackets and then compare to `0`

```
(strlen($_POST['date_year']) > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for advice. My stupid mistake. However I get error. I tried print_r($sql_execute); and get Array ( [0] => 05 [1] => 01 [2] => ) So it means that [2] => exists?

Comment: Yes this is because you make an array with three elements, and you pass those elements with variables which could be empty becuase of if statements about `$_POST` variables

Comment: Can not understand you comment about passing elements with variables (because of if statements)... any solution here?

Comment: `$sql_execute = array($post_date_day, $post_date_month, $post_date_year);` here you pass three variables, but the could be empty because the are filled with if statements. So this will create an array with three elements either if variables are empty or not.

Comment: I changed to `$sql_execute = array($_POST['date_day'], $_POST['date_month'], $_POST['date_year']);` The same result....

Comment: Yes you should build your array in if statements

Answer (score 4):

You will find it easier when creating a Dynamic query to add to the basic query when a parameter is available. Use a flag to switch from  WHERE to AND after the first parameter. The value is added to the data array at the same time.

Added error catch if no parameters passed and `$data[]`  empty.

```
$post_date_day =$_POST['date_day'];
$post_date_month = $_POST['date_month'];
$post_date_year = $_POST['date_year'];
$data = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal";
$flag = 0;//Set as WHERE
if (strlen($post_date_day)> 0) {
$query = $query." WHERE RecordDay = ?";
$data[]  =  $post_date_day;//Add to array
$flag = 1;//Switch to AND
}
if (strlen($post_date_month) > 0) {
if($flag ==0){
    $query.= " WHERE RecordMonth = ?";
    $flag = 1;//Switch to AND
  }else{
    $query.= " AND RecordMonth = ?";
  }
  $data[]  = $post_date_month;//Add to array
}
if (strlen($post_date_year) > 0) {
if($flag ==0){
    $query.= " WHERE RecordYear = ?";
  }else{
    $query.= " AND RecordYear = ?";
  }
  $data[]  = $post_date_year;//Add to array
}
$sql = $db->prepare($query);
if (empty($data)){//If no parameters passed
    $sql->execute();   
}else{
    $sql->execute($data); 
}
```